# Explore data frame and provide numbered list of variables in R

Tags: r

Working in R I find myself often trying to subset or use lapply on datasets using the variable number.

For example in an imaginary dataframe: df; in order to change the class of variables 1, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 18; to numeric I would use:

```
df[,c(1,4,6:12,15,19)] <- lapply(df[,c(1,4,6:12,15,19)], as.numeric)
```

When the dataframe is very large, trying to count the index number of the variables from `str()` or `glimpse()` can be extremely difficult.

Thus I am wondering whether there there a way to generate a representation of the variables contained in a dataset, indicating their name, their class and ideally a few of the entries (as is the case with `str()` and `glimpse()`), but with a number next to each variable name indicating its position?

`colnames()` is a partial solution in that the resulting chr vector has some numbering, buts not nearly as helpful as something like `str()` or `glimpse()`.

Comment: You can use `seq_along(df)` or `seq_len(ncol(df))` to get the sequence of column index

Comment: What is the class of those columns before you try to change it? You may create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @akrun : Thanks but that doesn't solve my problem. I don't just want a list of numbers. I want an object that shows the variable names (and ideally some useful information on their class etc.), and which numbers the variables.

Comment: If you need the class info, `v1 <- sapply(df, class)` and from this you can get the index of the variables `which(v1 == "numeric")` or directly `v1 <- sapply(df, is.character); which(v1)`

Comment: @markus I would be happy to provide a reproducible example, but i am not really trying to solve a specific problem here, i am more looking for a tool to that generally allows me to get information about the variables of a dataframe, including their column index.

Comment: @akrun that won't work if the things i am trying to change are all chr strings and i want to change some of them - based on the names i see in the dataframe - to numeric.

Comment: You create a vector of names based on the values you find and then use `i1 <- names(df1) %in% v2`

Comment: If you really want the program to make its on choices about which column name you want to change, use some deep learning platform and make it to learn by itself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really want something that just shows you column names, index and class you can write your own wrapper (and change the print output however you like).

```r
custom_glimpse <- function(df) {
  data.frame(
    col_name = colnames(df),
    col_index = 1:ncol(df),
    col_class = sapply(df, class),
    row.names = NULL
  )
}
custom_glimpse(mtcars)
#>    col_name col_index col_class
#> 1       mpg         1   numeric
#> 2       cyl         2   numeric
#> 3      disp         3   numeric
#> 4        hp         4   numeric
#> 5      drat         5   numeric
#> 6        wt         6   numeric
#> 7      qsec         7   numeric
#> 8        vs         8   numeric
#> 9        am         9   numeric
#> 10     gear        10   numeric
#> 11     carb        11   numeric
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is great, would it be possible to add a levels column to get all the unique levels for each? I added "col_elements = list(levels(P_Region_HP))", but that unsurprisingly didn't work. Any thought? (I know this would be sub-optimal where you have numeric or date class columns, but would be helpful for character columns.)

Answer (score 0):

for some reason, when I tried out the script by @Calum You, I kept getting errors related to the lengths. So through process of elimination, I found the error to be related to the `col_class` line. So I had to modify my script a bit to make it work.

Here goes my script:

```
# get list of columns
custom_glimpse <- function(df) {
    data.frame(
        col_name = colnames(df),
        col_index = 1:ncol(df),
        col_class = unlist(sapply(df[, -1], class)),
        row.names = NULL

        )
    }

custom_glimpse(myDF)
```